# fread e alocação de memória de estrutura

Tags: c, arquivo, struct, alocação

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
typedef struct registro {//52 bytes
    char codigo[4];
    char descricao[31];
    char unidade[3];
    int quantidade;
    float valor;
    char status;
  }registro;
```

A mesma deve guardar os valores de um arquivo `dados.dat`, previamente organizado para ser armazenado nesta estrutura. Para alocar espaço de acordo com os agrupamentos de itens presentes no arquivo aloco memória dinamicamente através de um ponteiro do tipo registro. Porém na hora de puxar os dados do arquivo e grava-los na estrutura a mensagem "Erro na escrita", presente no laço de gravação aparece, e nada é gravado na estrutura. Eis o código:

```
void Ex10(){
    registro *lista;
    int i,cont=0;
    FILE *fp;
    char arquiv[100],caracter;

    puts("Digite o nome do arquivo(padrao:dados.dat):");
    scanf("%s",&arquiv);
    fp = fopen(arquiv,"r");

    while(!feof(fp)){
        caracter = getc(fp);
        cont++;
    }
    cont = cont - 1;
    cont = cont / 52;

    lista = malloc(cont * sizeof(registro));

    if(lista == NULL){
        printf("Erro de alocação de memória.\n");
        system("PAUSE");
    }else{
        puts("Alocado com sucesso!!");
    }

    for (i=0; i<cont; i++) {
        if (fread( &lista[cont], sizeof(struct registro), 1, fp) != 1) {//adiciona todos os dados.dat na estrutura
            puts("Erro na escrita.");
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<cont; i++) {
        printf("Codigo = %s\n", lista[i].codigo);
        printf("Descricao  = %s\n\n", lista[i].descricao);
        printf("Unidade  = %s\n\n", lista[i].unidade);
        printf("Quantidade  = %d\n\n", lista[i].quantidade);
        printf("Valor  = %f\n\n", lista[i].valor);
        printf("Status  = %c\n\n", lista[i].status);
    }
}
```

Caso não haja alocação dinâmica, o programa grava normalmente os dados na estrutura,ou seja, quando a declaração é feita da seguinte forma: `registro lista[6]`, porém desta forma é necessário saber quantas informações existem dentro do arquivo, coisa que nem sempre será possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está lendo todo o arquivo pra calcular o tamanho. Antes de lê-lo novamente para a estrutura, você precisa fazer um `fseek()` para voltar ao início.

Há formas mais eficientes de calcular o tamanho do arquivo. Consulte `ftell()` e `fstat()`. Estas funções te dão o tamanho do arquivo sem precisar ler todo o conteúdo.